# CRCError: Invalid Projection: EPSG:4326 for Sentinel API Script & AttributeError: module 'pyproj'

Tags: python, remote-sensing, sentinel-2, pyproj

I am realatively new to Python programming and have an issue with pyproj mixing up the CRS database (this is what I gather from the web).  I have a little script I've written to retrieve Sentinel images and get the following error:

> ~\anaconda3\envs\Raster\lib\site-packages\pyproj\crs\crs.py in
> **init**(self, projparams, **kwargs)
> 294             projstring = _prepare_from_string(" ".join((projstring, projkwargs)))
> 295
> --> 296         super().**init**(projstring)
> 297
> 298     @staticmethod
>
> pyproj/_crs.pyx in pyproj._crs._CRS.**init**()
>
> CRSError: Invalid projection: EPSG:4326: (Internal Proj Error:
> proj_create: SQLite error on SELECT name, type,
> coordinate_system_auth_name, coordinate_system_code, datum_auth_name,
> datum_code, area_of_use_auth_name, area_of_use_code, text_definition,
> deprecated FROM geodetic_crs WHERE auth_name = ? AND code = ?: no such
> column: area_of_use_auth_name)

It all started after I had some problems with the environment this program was written in, and just created a new environment with all the modules installed, but now my once working program is not working.  The error is a known issue as stated on the pyproj page, but I am at a loss on how to actually solve it.

I have tried pyproj.datadir.get_data_dir() in jupyter and I get the following read out:

```
C:\\Users\\Matthew\\anaconda3\\envs\\Raster\\lib\\site- 
packages\\pyproj\\proj_dir\\share\\proj'
```

This checks out.  The virtual environment is Raster as stated.

I also did a pip uninstall in the Raster environment via CMD.  Then I tried running it again and got the following:

> ```
> ~\anaconda3\envs\Raster\lib\site-packages\geopandas\_compat.py in <module>
>     210 # -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
>     211 
> --> 212 PYPROJ_LT_3 = LooseVersion(pyproj.__version__) < LooseVersion("3")
> ```

AttributeError: module 'pyproj' has no attribute '**version**'

The program code is below:

```
# -- Connect to the ESA Server via Sentinel Application Programming Interface (API) --
from sentinelsat import SentinelAPI, read_geojson, geojson_to_wkt
from datetime import date
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import folium
import pandas as pd


# -- Username & Password Login Information --

user = 'xxxxxxx' 
password = 'xxxxxxxx' 
api = SentinelAPI(user, password, 'https://apihub.copernicus.eu/apihub')

# server locations
#https://scihub.copernicus.eu/dhu
#https://apihub.copernicus.eu/apihub


# Create footprint for search

aoi = geojson_to_wkt(read_geojson(r"C:\Users\Matthew\OneDrive \Land Suitability Model"
                                  r"\Layers\Sentinel\Sentinel RST\aoi.geojson"))

# Search query

products = api.query(aoi,
                     date = ('20210715', '20210814'),  # year (xxxx), month (xx), day (xx)
                     platformname = 'Sentinel-2', # Sentinel-2 (10,20m,60m MSI), Sentinel-1 (20m SAR)
                     processinglevel = 'Level-2A',  # can change to 2A or 1C processed image tiles
                     cloudcoverpercentage = (0,5)  # from % to % <=40
                     )

# Review available image tiles (sorted by cloud cover)
products_gdf = api.to_geodataframe(products)
products_gdf_sorted = products_gdf.sort_values(['cloudcoverpercentage'], ascending=[True])
products_df1 = pd.DataFrame(products_gdf_sorted) 
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

# Display Sentinel Query Results
print('Number of Sentinel Products:',len(products))
display(products_df1[['title','uuid','generationdate','cloudcoverpercentage','size','processinglevel']])
query_footprints = api.to_geojson(products)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None) 
# -- Display AOI and Sentinel-2A query results --

# Use if your interested in a point
# AOI = 'POINT (xxx xxx)'

# Set style list for AOI
style = {'fillColor': '#ffff00', 'color': '#000000'}

# Read in AOI & Query footprints
AOI = gpd.read_file(r"C:\Users\Matthew\OneDrive\Land Suitability Model\Layers\Sentinel"
                    r"\Sentinel RST\aoi.geojson")
mainmap = folium.Map(
    location =[56.730259, -121.808989], zoom_start=7,
)
folium.GeoJson(query_footprints).add_to(mainmap)
folium.GeoJson(AOI,style_function = lambda x:style).add_to(mainmap)
mainmap
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve the issue I created a new virtual environment and reinstalled modules using the following command:

```shell
conda install geopandas --channel=conda-forge
pip install sentinelsat
conda install matplotlib --channel=conda-forge
conda install folium --channel=conda-forge
```